# Get the value inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

im fairly new to python and im doing a RPG to practice what i'm learning. I have a dictionary of items and i want to get the name of one of them, but when i call it i get a message :

```
You don't have any<classes.inventory.Item object at 0x7f52e39bce48>left!
```

My dictionary is this one:

```
player_items = [{"item":potion, "quantity": 15},
                {"item":hipotion, "quantity": 10},
                {"item":superpotion, "quantity": 8},
                {"item":elixir, "quantity": 3},
                {"item":hielixir, "quantity":1},
                {"item":grenade, "quantity": 12}]

item = player.items[item_choice]["item"]
player.items[item_choice]["quantity"] -= 1

if player.items[item_choice]["quantity"] == 0:
    print(bcolors.FAIL+"\n"+"You don't have any"+str(item)+"left!"+bcolors.ENDC)

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, type, description, prop):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.description = description
        self.prop = prop

class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic, items):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkhigh = atk+10
        self.atklow = atk-10
        self.df = df
        self.items = items
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic", "Items"]
```

Anyone know what im doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT : Found the error. I need to learn more. I just needed to add the name property when i called the item :

```
print(bcolors.FAIL+"\n"+"You don't have any"+str(item.name)+"left!"+bcolors.ENDC)
```

Sorry i wasted your time guys.

Comment: This code is fine, and you're doing nothing wrong

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code in your program? your dictionary is called `player_items` but you perform your operations on `player.items`. so is the dict a global scoped dict or is it a member of a player instance?

Comment: Yes, this is the code, the inventory has a Item class and is part of the player too, let me paste the rest of the code :                                                     class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, type, description, prop):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.description = description
        self.prop = prop

Comment: Could you please edit the code in your comment into the question? It would make it easier to read

Comment: Sure, done editing.

Answer (score 2):

`item` isn't the string `"potion"`, for instance; it's a reference to an instance of `Item` that represents a potion. You need to provide an appropriate `__str__` method for your `Item` class.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

@Ifsalazar2010 welcome to python. here are a few things I see you may be doing wrong.

First, your dict values need to be string, otherwise python will try to look for those as object. So write `"potion"` instead of `potion`

```
player_items = [{"item":"potion", "quantity": 15},
            {"item":"hipotion", "quantity": 10},
            {"item":"superpotion", "quantity": 8},
            {"item":"elixir", "quantity": 3},
            {"item":"hielixir", "quantity":1},
            {"item":"grenade", "quantity": 12}]
```

Next, you need to use the proper object `player_items` and not `player.items`. Your object is a list of dictionaries, which you can call by index and you haven't defined `item_choice`. I am using the index `1` as example.

```
item = player_items[1]["item"]
print(item)
player_items[1]["quantity"] -= 1
print(player_items)
```

In short, seems like you didn't provide detail in your example to replicate your errors. for example what is `bcolors.FAIL`

Comment: oh, bcolors is a class for colors for the font. I have them in bash saved in those variables, for example bcolors.FAIL = '\033[91m'